# What is the best way to pass arguments to user defined function called from a string in R?

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I feel this is really simple and I am just missing a simple function. I have user defined functions in my environment. `Open`, `Weak`, `Strong` etc.

I have a variable within my code, which based on criteria, selects one of these functions to run.

```
Fun_Sel<-case_when(TP < 6 ~ "Pass",
                   6  <= TP & TP <= 11 ~ "Weak",
                   12 <= TP & TP <= 12 ~ "Rule22",
                   13 <= TP & TP <= 21 ~ "Open",
                   TP >= 22 ~ "Strong")
```

When I use the built in `get`function on `Fun_Sel` I get

```
get(Fun_Sel)
function(df){

  if( 15 <= as.numeric(df[2]) & as.numeric(df[2]) <= 17 & df[4] == "Bal"){....
```

Using `eval(parse(text=Fun_Sel))` gives me same issue

How do I pass arguments and run the function instead of getting a print out in the console of the function itself?

Comment: Try `get(Fun_Sel)()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, gettting Fun_Sel with get() will only return the function object itself. That's it' being printed on the console. It's the fact that you place ()'s after the function that activates it and places a function call. You may include the desired parameters inside the ()'s.

```
get(Fun_Sel)(par1, par2, etc)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew it was simple